# Error : TS2339 Property 'shape' does not exist on type 'typeof create'

Tags: typescript, yup

```
import * as yup from 'yup';

const loginSchema = yup.object.shape({
    email: yup.string().required('Email Required !'),
    pswd: yup.string().required('Password Required !')
  });
```

Error is in shape does not exist in yup.object whereas [official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup) uses same.

**Thanks in advance for help!**

Comment: You have a typo there. It should be `yup.object().shape()`

Comment: Made the same typo and was stuck for half an hour :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an typo yup.obejct.shape() It should be yup.object().shape().